# angular hybrid - webpack - nomod

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack

I am trying to implement webpack for angular hybrid( using ngupgrade ) but I am getting an error

> Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

'app' is my angular 1 module name,

Sample code in my angular 2 main.ts file

```
declare var angular:any;
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter( AppModule );

angular.module('app').directive('appComponent', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Anyone has encountered similar issue ?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
    });
```

**angular 2 upgrade file: main.ts**

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppModule} from  './app.module';

declare var angular:any;
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter( AppModule );
angular.module('app').directive('appComponent', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.ts file try following code

```
 import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
 import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
 import {AppModule} from  './app.module';

 declare var angular:any;
 var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter( AppModule );
 angular.module('app',[]);
 angular.module('app').directive('appComponent',     
 adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
 adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

I think you were missing the declaration of ur module coz ur using directive before module declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `angular.module` you need to include an array of dependencies, that's the '`[]`' for. After that, you can get hold of the app module again by calling `angular.module('app')`

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('appComponent', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
```